# Adding User to a group

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, user, grouping

I am a MS CRM Developer. I am writing a plugin in CRM. We have an on premises deployment of SharePoint and CRM. In my plugin my requirement is:-

1. I have login name of user, I want to check whether users is an existing user of SharePoint, if not add it.
2. I have the Group Name of SharePoint, I want to add the above user to that Group.

Comment: I am new to sharepoint. I would be grateful if someone can guide in how I will write code for sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePoint web services.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774422(v=office.12).aspx

First you should get all users from the group and check if user exists or not and then use AddUserToGroup